# How would I get my divs to center after a media query breakpoint?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Working on making my site responsive. After a certain width I want one of my divs to fall down below the two before it, with the divs becoming centered. The problem is right now all they do is stay left aligned after the breakpoint. How would I make them centered on the page again after the breakpoint?

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Reset */

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}

/* Site Wide CSS */

body {
    max-width: 100%; 
    margin: 0;   
    font-size: 16px;   
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;  
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;   
    color: #555; 
}

p {
 text-align: center; 
}

/* Nav Bar Styles */

nav {
    text-align: right;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #fff; 
 font-size: 1.4em;
 padding: 0;
 padding-top: .5%;
 padding-bottom: .6%;
   
}

ul {
 padding-right: 2%; 
}

.navigation {
    display: inline;
    margin: .5%;
  
}

.logo {
 color:#000; 
 display: inline;
 float: left;
 margin: 0 0 0 1%;
}

/* Footer */

footer {
    text-align: center;
 padding-top: 2%;
 padding-bottom: .5%;  
 font-size: 79%;
 color: #000;
 background-color: #fff; 
 clear: left;
   
}

footer i.fa {
 font-size: 3.5em;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; 
}

footer i.fa-facebook-square:hover { 

color: #3b5998;
 
}

footer i.fa-instagram:hover { 

color: #125688;
 
}

footer i.fa-flickr:hover { 

color: #ff0084;
 
}


footer i.fa-twitter-square:hover { 

color: #00aced;
 
}

/* Font Awesome */

i.fa {
 font-size: 2.3em; 
}



.container {
    padding-top: 2.5%; 
 padding-bottom: 2.5%;  
}

/* Banner */

div.background {
 margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
 min-height: 650px;
 background-image: url("../img/landscapes/br.jpg");
 background-sizeP: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat; 
 
}

/* Skills */

div.container {
 width: 100%; 
 min-height: 175px;
 color: #000;
 margin: 0; 
 text-align: center; 
}

.skills {
 float: left;
 width: 33%;
 margin-bottom: 1.8%; 
}

.expertise {
 text-align: center;
 margin: 2% 2% 1% 2%;
 font-size: 1.2em; 
}

.details {
 padding: 2%; 
}

a.btn {
   width: 11%;
   margin: auto;
   padding: .6%;
   text-align: center; 
   border: 1px solid #fff;
   font-size: 1.2em;
   background-color: #000;
   color: #fff;
   border-radius: 9px;   
}

.btn:hover {
 
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
 border: solid 1px #000;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

/* Media Queries */

@media only screen and (max-width: 1070px) {
    .photo .design {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto; 
 }
 
 .web {
        clear: left;
    }
 
 a.btn { clear: left;
 }}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Brian Funderburke Photography &amp; Design</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/sitewide.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/home.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
<header>
  
    <nav>
        <h1 class="logo">B.Fun Photography &amp; Design</h1>
            <ul>
                <li class="navigation"><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
                <li class="navigation"><a href="photography.html">Photography</a></li>
                <li class="navigation"><a href="design.html">Design</a></li>
                <li class="navigation"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li class="navigation"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
    </nav>
    
</header>

<div class="background">
</div>

<div class="container photo">
    <div class="skills">
        <i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i>
            <h2 class="expertise">Photography</h2>
                <p class="details">Let me capture your beautiful moments for you! I shoot everything from weddings to landscapes.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="skills design">
     <i class="fa fa-paint-brush"></i>
            <h2 class="expertise">Design</h2>
                <p class="details">From logo design to business cards. Your products deserve to look beautiful.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="skills web">
     <i class="fa fa-code"></i>
            <h2 class="expertise">Web Development</h2>
                <p class="details">Handcrafted websites help ensure you stand out in today's crowded online ecosystem!</p>
    </div>
    <a href="contact.html" class="btn">Get In Touch!</a>
</div>

<footer>
 <i class="fa fa-instagram footerSocial"><a href="https://www.instagram.com/bfunphoto/"></a></i>
    <i class="fa fa-flickr footerSocial"><a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/bfunder94/"></a></i>
 <i class="fa fa-facebook-square"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/BFunPhoto"></a></i>
    <i class="fa fa-twitter-square"><a href="https://twitter.com/BFunPhoto"></a></i>
    <p>&#169; 2016 Brian Funderburke. All Rights Reserved.</p>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

The CSS media query in question:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1070px) {
.photo .design {
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;   
}

.web {
    clear: left;
}

a.btn { clear: left;
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You were close, just change the css to target the `skills` element, add a width of 100% to `skills` class, and `text-align:center` like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1070px) {
  .skills {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
  }
  .web {
    clear: left;
  }
  a.btn {
    clear: left;
  }
}
```

See example: https://jsfiddle.net/kh0prtc4/12/

Answer (score 1):

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9Le8cyfa/1/)

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1070px) {
.photo {
    text-align: center;
}

.skills {

    display: inline-block; 
    float: none;
}
}
```

and remove 'Get in touch' button (put it after or before) like

```
<div class="container photo">
<div class="skills">
    <i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i>
        <h2 class="expertise">Photography</h2>
            <p class="details">Let me capture your beautiful moments for you! I shoot everything from weddings to landscapes.</p>
</div>
<div class="skills design">
    <i class="fa fa-paint-brush"></i>
        <h2 class="expertise">Design</h2>
            <p class="details">From logo design to business cards. Your products deserve to look beautiful.</p>
</div>
<div class="skills web">
    <i class="fa fa-code"></i>
        <h2 class="expertise">Web Development</h2>
            <p class="details">Handcrafted websites help ensure you stand out in today's crowded online ecosystem!</p>
</div>
</div>
 <div style="text-align: center;">
    <a href="contact.html" class="btn">Get In Touch!</a>
 </div>
```

from the main div, so it won't break the layout.
And if you set width to your divs(class skills) it will work as expected!
Hopefully it helped!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you would like all the divs to be stacked and centered while view port is a smaller screen.  To achieve this with the code you have provided make the give the divs a width of 100%.  Here is the CSS that shows what to add.  Again, I hope this answers the question.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1070px) {
.photo .design {
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;   
}

.web {
    clear: left;
}

/*the part I added*/
.skills {
  width: 100%;


}
a.btn { clear: left;
}}
```

Answer (score -1):

The following in the stylesheet
div{align: center; }
However if you are using an inline style it is 
style='text-align: center'